# How to sort my data according to month order? I want my month order to be april to april (that is the financial year)

Tags: pandas, sorting, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

I have plotted a graph of months versus business turnover, but the months are not in order. They are rather alphabetically ordered. I want them to be ordered as in a financial year i.e. april, may, june......march.

This is how the dataframe is.

```
Month_name       CASH/TPA   Total

April            CASH       2184074.0

August           CASH       1780238.0

December         CASH       1176889.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 How to convert date into monthly periods where the first period is September](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931471/python3-how-to-convert-date-into-monthly-periods-where-the-first-period-is-septe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ordered categoricals with order defined in parameter `categories`:

```
months = ['April','May','June','July','August',
          'September','October','November',
          'December','January','February','March']

df['Month_name'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['Month_name'], ordered=True, categories=months)
```

If need sorting by `Month_name`:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('Month_name')
```

Or by both columns:

```
df2 = df.sort_values(['CASH/TPA', 'Month_name'])
```

Or if necessary, [pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe):

```
df3 = df.pivot('Month_name','CASH/TPA','Total')
```

Comment: months = ['April','May','June','July','August',
          'September','October','November',
          'December','January','February','March']

Comment: df.set_index('Month_name')

Comment: df['Month_name'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['Month_name'], ordered=True, categories=months)

Comment: df1 = df.sort_values('Month_name')

Comment: this is exactly what I did and I get the error :-   KeyError: 'Month_name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: @Kopal Sharma Can you test this? `months = ['April','May','June','July','August', 'September','October','November', 'December','January','February','March']`

`df = df.set_index('Month_name')`
`df.index= pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index, ordered=True, categories=months)`
`df1 = df.sort_index()`

Comment: @Kopal Karma If not working, try this `months = ['April','May','June','July','August', 'September','October','November', 'December','January','February','March']`

`df.index= pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index, ordered=True, categories=months)`
`df1 = df.sort_index()`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Month_name']=pd.to_datetime(df.Month_name, format='%B', errors='coerce').dt.month.map("{:02}".format)
```

---

```
  Month_name CASH/TPA      Total
0      April     CASH  2184074.0
1     August     CASH  1780238.0
2   December     CASH  1176889.0
  Month_name CASH/TPA      Total
0         04     CASH  2184074.0
1         08     CASH  1780238.0
2         12     CASH  1176889.0
```

Comment: It gives an error saying dataframe has no attribute named Month_name

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Month_name'

Comment: Try df['Month_name']

Comment: @KopalSharma it really works on my end in both ways :)

Comment: It is still not working ... But Thank you for all the help!

Comment: No worries, check your pandas version. I tested on 0.24.2. Apparently the latest one.